# Flipboard is not fetching post feature image

Tags: flipboard

Flipboard isn't fetching the post image from one of my websites, while the other is working perfectly on it. I am also attaching the image for you to see.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened due to WebP, I contacted Flipboard, their customer service confirmed that their platform doesn't support WebP that's why the thumbnails of posts with WebP featured image will not be processed.